# How to read data from a password-protected Excel worksheet

Tags: asp.net, excel, oledb

I've been looking for an answer for that problem, I just can't read my password-protected Excel file, but when I try with a copy of that file (without password) it works, this is my connection string, I'm using OleDB

```
var excelConn = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;user id=;password=P-ICS'";
```

My OleDbCommand:

```
oleDbCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MS Access;database=" + accessFilePath + "].[temp]"+
                           "SELECT [Create],[Lote],[Qtd],[F10],[Término Real],[Número da Ordem]" +
                           "FROM [R 1120$]";
```

That's all, sorry about my English, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Excel workbook is protected by a password, you cannot open it for data access, even by supplying the correct password with your connection string.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Answer (score -1):

According to http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel, you can't. They do, however, provide a workaround for locally run scripts.

> If the Excel workbook is protected by a password, you cannot open it for data access, even by supplying the correct password with your connection string. If you try, you receive the following error message: "Could not decrypt file."